# Problem with revolving EP Curve in Maya 2012?

Tags: maya, curves

I am trying to create a animated butterfly i made this using the EP curve 
[image]

but when i try to revolve this it turns out to be this[image]

can anyone tell me what is the [roblem

Thanks

Akash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not HAVE to use the right side of the left side.

You actually choose around which axis you want your EP curve to revolve:
[image]

If you have a curve like this one:
[image]

You can revolve around X-axis:
[image]

You can revolve around Y-axis:
[image]

You can revolve around Z-axis
[image]

Or you can revolve around a freely defined axis (1,1,-1 here):
[image]